App instantly crashes when Allowing the app permission for location
I'm experiencing an issue with my app. It works fine when testing on Expo Go, but when I build the app (using EAS), it crashes immediately after I allow the app to access my location. Does anyone know what might be causing this or how I can resolve it?
I've tried properly requesting location permissions in the code, ensured my app.json has the correct permissions set, and checked that location services are enabled on my device. Despite these efforts, I'm still facing the crash
Here is a another version just to try it. But still not working.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function MapScreen() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      try {
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(location);
      } catch (error) {
        setErrorMsg('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {errorMsg ? (
        <Text>{errorMsg}</Text>
      ) : location ? (
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.005,
            longitudeDelta: 0.005,
          }}
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.coords.latitude,
              longitude: location.coords.longitude,
            }}
            title="Your Location"
          />
        </MapView>
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading map...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});


Try commenting out the UI temporarily and display the value of location in an alert in the release build. It is very likely that location may be undefined or null.
